# Angular Checkbox : Changes not reflecting properly

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing an issue in my Angular project where I have multiple checkboxes in an options form. The problem is that sometimes changes in the checkboxes are not reflected properly. Here's the relevant code:

```html
<form class="theme-form">
    <div *ngFor="let contactType of contactTypeDataList" class="checkbox-theme">
        <label [for]="contactType.Type" class="arrow-labe2">
            <input class="form-control" [id]="contactType.TypeId" class="styled" type="checkbox"
                [checked]="contactType.IsActive"
                [value]="contactType.TypeId" (change)="onTypeCheckboxChange($event, contactType)">
            {{ contactType.Type }}
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: do you see any error? is there a specific pattern when it misbehaves?
would be really helpful if a minimum reproducible example is present.

Comment: I Have No Error

Comment: Describe exact what are you doing, what is expected result and what is actual result. If tou have no error it might be change detection issue, but I don't know when and how you encounter something unexpected

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem you setting statically [id]="" when you should set it dynamically [attr.id]=""

```
<form class="theme-form">
    <div *ngFor="let contactType of contactTypeDataList" class="checkbox-theme">
        <label for="contactType.Type" class="arrow-labe2">
            <input class="form-control styled" [attr.id]="contactType.TypeId"  type="checkbox"
                [checked]="contactType.IsActive"
                [value]="contactType.TypeId" (change)="onTypeCheckboxChange($event, contactType)">
            {{ contactType.Type }}
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```